# Detecting progress on a Youtube video to change the state of a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-api, custom-wordpress-pages

On my Wordpress page, I have multiple Youtube videos embedded on 1 page per video. I would like to change something on the page if a Youtube video has been watched for at least 80%
This feature should work no matter if the video was watched on Youtube directly or in the embedded player.
Is that possible to implement and if yes, how?

Comment: may be you can't track outside of your page but within your page you can try using YouTube api to know where video was paused or stopped events etc.

Comment: I think what you need is to use the [Playlist reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/content_owner_reports#playlist-reports). But it was stated that it was already deprecated so try to follow the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/migration) given in the documentation to move ahead.